# is there something i'm missing in displaying plotOutput() (bs4Dash)

Tags: bs4dash

```
 library(shiny)
library(gapminder)
library(bbplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(bs4Dash)

year_range <- range(gapminder[["year"]])

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(
      title = dashboardBrand(
        title = "LE",
        color = "gray"
      )
      
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      width = ,
      skin = "light",
      
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidemenu",
        
        menuItem(
          "plotme",
          tabName = "plotme",
          icon = icon("sliders")
        )
        
      )
      
    ),
    
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabItem(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "plotme",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 12,
              plotOutput("plotme")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      collapsed = FALSE,
      pinned = TRUE,
      skin = "light",
      
      controlbarMenu(
        id = "plotme",
        
        controlbarItem(
        
            title = "Filter:",
            selectInput("continent", "Continent",
                        choices = unique(gapminder$continent)),

          
            selectInput("country", "Country",
                        choices = NULL),
            
            sliderInput("year",
                        "Select The Year Range:",
                        min = year_range[[1]],
                        max = year_range[[2]],
                        value = c(year_range[[1]], year_range[[2]]),
                        sep = "",
                        step = 1)
            
          
        )
        
      )
    ),
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  continent_data <- reactive({
    gapminder %>%
      filter(continent == input$continent
             & year >= input$year[[1]] | year <= input$year[[2]])
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(continent_data(), {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "country")
    choices <- unique(continent_data()$country)
    updateSelectInput(session, "country", choices = choices)
  })
  
  country_data <- reactive({
    req(input$continent)
    continent_data() %>%
      filter(country == input$country
             & year >= input$year[[1]] & year <= input$year[[2]])
  })
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$country)
    ggplot(country_data(), aes(year, lifeExp)) +
      geom_line(colour = "#1380A1", size = 1) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1, colour="#333333")
  }, res = 96)
  

  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have checked the reactive elements and it seems fine. My guess is the issue might be from the menuItems() or from dashboardcontrolbar()

The UI is displaying alright but the plotOutput is not showing

I have checked the reactive elements and it seems fine. My guess is the issue might be from the menuItems() or from dashboardcontrolbar()

The UI is displaying alright but the plotOutput is not showing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the app but maybe the problem is with the id's.

You are using `plotOutput("plotme")` in the UI and `output$plot` in the server function.